# Logical OR operator in IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want if col1_list is not null or not empty or if col2_list is not null or not empty do some logic and set rc = 0, else set rc = 1 . If some of col_list is null or empty set rc 1 . But logical OR operator not work in if statement or what I'm doing wrong ?

```
declare @col1_list varchar(max) , @col2_list varchar(max)
declare @tbl TABLE (col1 int , col2 int)
declare @rc char(1) = '0'
set @col1_list = '2|6|7|8|'
set @col2_list = '1|'

IF (@col1_list IS NOT NULL OR @col1_list <> '' OR @col2_list IS NOT NULL OR @col2_list <> '')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @myXML1 AS XML = N'<H><r>' + REPLACE(@col1_list, '|', '</r><r>') + '</r></H>'
    DECLARE @myXML2 AS XML = N'<H><r>' + REPLACE(@col2_list, '|', '</r><r>') + '</r></H>';

    with mycte as (SELECT Vals1.id.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS val1
    FROM @myXML1.nodes('/H/r') AS Vals1(id)),
    mycte1 as (SELECT Vals2.id.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS val2
    FROM @myXML2.nodes('/H/r') AS Vals2(id))

    insert into @tbl (col1,col2)
    select val1,val2
    from mycte,mycte1
    where val1 <> '' and val2 <> ''
    set @rc = '0'
END 
    ELSE
        set @rc ='1'

    select @rc as [rc]
```

**Have Rc = 0 when some of col_list is null or empty**

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: When you say that it is not working, explain what you want and what you actually get

Comment: I have rc = 0 when some of col_list is null or empty

Comment: `declare @rc char(1) = '00'` its CHAR(1) and you are assigning two character to it. Not fair :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your if condition to this:

```
IF (NOT(@col1_list IS NULL OR @col1_list = '') AND NOT(@col2_list IS NULL OR @col2_list = ''))
```

This one checks 2 things:

1. `@col1_list` is neither null nor empty, AND
2. `@col2_list` is neither null nor empty.

Comment: I want when some of col_list is empty or is null query must enterd in else statement and set @rc = 1 but it doesnot entered in else statement